# Angular PWA Not Working on iOS - Service Worker Errors

Tags: javascript, angular, safari, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

I have an Angular app that I've converted into a Progressive Web App (PWA) for mobile. It works perfectly fine on Android devices, but I'm encountering issues on iOS. Sometimes, the webpage doesn't open, and the service worker console is full of errors like this: [image: errors]

Additionally, when the webpage doesn't load, I see a blank screen with the following error:

[image: error screen on mobile]

I've been searching for information online, but I haven't been able to find any solutions or similar cases. I'm not sure what might be causing these issues specifically on iOS.

Can anyone provide guidance on what could be causing these errors on iOS and how to resolve them? I'm open to suggestions and insights. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: probably an error in some code somewhere - or perhaps safari being incompatible with every other browser in existence (more likely) - thing is, do any of the errors mean anything to you? I mean, do they resonate with some code you may have written? because all you've posted is an image of a vague error, there's too many possible things you've done wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your replay. There are only these errors and they don't mean anything to me. This does not happen when reinstalling the app, but after some time it occurs again.

Comment: Yeah, so what code is causing those errors. We can't see if your code is poorly written or not

Comment: Looks like that's similar to my problem, but it doesn't answer my question. Thank you